# What are the sim card options in Belarus for a tourist?

Tags: cellphones, belarus, minsk

I'm traveling to Minsk and would like to get a local sim while I'm there (only for data). What are my options? Can I buy a sim card at Minsk airport?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Getting connected to the cell network in Belarus is only allowed after presenting identification (a passport).

One option for non-residents is to acquire a local SIM-card by **MTS** carrier called [MTS SMART Guest](http://en.mts.by/tariffs/for_guests/tourist/) for 12.5 roubles (~7$).
You can sign up [in the airport](https://foursquare.com/v/%D0%BC%D1%82%D1%81/4dc407662271f27051085f89) by showing your international passport or ID. The customer center is opened from 9AM to 9PM.
Detailed location of the center can be seen [on this map](http://airport.by/sites/default/files/images/map/f1b.jpg) (red MTS logo near gates 5 and 6)

There is another option from **Privet** (as suggested by [vcsjonesq](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/918/vcsjones)). Their [rules](http://privet.by/ru/faq/connect/) say that non-residents are allowed. They offer four tariff options from which you [can choose](http://privet.by/en/tarifs/) based on your needs.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, Velcom has a "Privet" package that tourists may use as well. I don't think it's any better than MTS, but its an option. I've had better luck with Velcom in more rural areas signal wise.

Comment: @vcsjonesq, yes, you are right. I didn't know such thing. Corrected the answer accordingly.